# (PostgreSQL) 12.7 (Ubuntu 12.7-0ubuntu0.20.04.1) can't connect to the database?

Tags: postgresql, runtime-error, wsl-2

This is on WSl 2 following the instructions from the [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/tutorials/wsl-database#install-postgresql)

I created a simple postgresql and I try to connect to it like so:

```js
const Sequelize = require("sequelize");

const sequelize = new Sequelize('postgres://postgres:w@localhost:5432/messenger', {
  logging: false,
  dialect: 'postgre'
});

async function test(){
  try {
    await sequelize.authenticate();
    console.log('Connection has been established successfully.');
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Unable to connect to the database:', error);
  }
}

test();
```

This will tell me if the connection was successful or not, but for some reason, I keep getting this error. The URI string seems correct, the only user is the default created Postgres where I changed the password to be "w" for testing purposes.

Not sure what that 12/main part is about but the server is online so I am really not sure what the problem is.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either you specified the wrong password for the database user "postgres", or your server isn't configured to allow password authentication on localhost. You can see this link: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/auth-methods.html for more information on the authentication methods postgresql supports, or this one: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/auth-pg-hba-conf.html for information on how to set up authentication on your postgresql server.

Comment: From the documentation I was following, I had to change the password for user postgres

Comment: If you're sure the password is correct, then your server isn't set up to use password authentication for connections on localhost. I believe that by default postgres is set up to use the "peer" authentication type on localhost, and "password" authentication for remote connections. The links I posted above to the postgresql documentation explain how to figure out what authentication method your postgresql server is using, and how to change it if needed.

Comment: Was trying to find the file location but how exactly do you reach it, SHOW hba_file got me this directory /etc/postgresql/12/main/pg_hba.conf I couldn't open it with vi "/path"

Comment: If you're not logged in as the user who owns the file, you most likely need sudo vi "/path/to/file" to edit it with elevated privileges. But if that doesn't let you edit it, I'm not sure. I haven't used postgres on WSL or Ubuntu, so anything specific to that environment I may not be able to be much help.